# Rails count linked tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three objects that are linked to each other. It looks like this:

```
tree[
  id: 1,
  name: "name"
]

branch[
  id: 1,
  tree_id: 1
]

leaf[
  id: 1,
  branch_id:1
]
```

I need to know how many leaves belong to a every tree so I created a nested for loop:

**update**

I updated code:

```
results = []
trees = Tree.all
trees.each do |tree|
  branches = Branch.where(tree_id: tree.id)
  branches.each do |branch|
   leaves_count = leaves.where(branch_id: branch.id).count
  end
  results.push( {
    tree: tree.name,
    leaves: leaves_count
  })
end
```

with this code I receive an array of objects like so:

```
results = [{  
    tree: "oak",
    leaves: 4
  }, {
    tree: "redwood",
    leaves: 6
}]
```

I would like the same output but in a rails way

This works but feels realy clunky. Does anyone know a rails way of fixing this?

**update solved**

Yury Lebedev's answer is correct but through his previous answer I found another way. So this works (yury's answer):

```
Tree.find_each do |tree|
  Branch.where(tree_id: tree.id).joins(:leaves).count('leaves.id')
end
```

This also works:

```
Tree.find_each do |tree|
  Tree.joins(branches: :leaves).where(id: tree.id).count('leaves.id')
end
```

As a continuation question (not sure if I'm supposed to do that on answered questions?) I would like to know i one is better/faster then the other or whether they'r the same.

Comment: Does your **class name** for leaves is `Leaves` or `Leaf`?

Comment: class name is leaf, i'll edit it.

Comment: Does this work `Leaf.includes(branches: [:trees]).count` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: Well the main problem is that it only gives one count, but need a count of leaves PER tree. so 1 result for every tree i have. the result i get is always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with a join query (this will only make one query to the db):

```
Leaf.joins('inner join branches on leaves.branch_id = branches.id')
  .group('branches.tree_id').count
```

This will give you a hash with `tree_id` as a keys, and leaves count as values.

If you want to iterate through the trees, and get the leaves count for each of them, you can do this (this will make n queries to the db, if you have n trees):

```
trees.each do |tree|
  leaves_count = Branch.where(tree_id: tree.id).joins('inner join leaves on leaves.branch_id = branches.id')
    .count('leaves.id')
end
```

And this can be done even easier, if you have associations in your models:

```
class Three < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :branches
  has_many :trees, through: :branches
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tree
  has_many :leaves
end

class Leaf < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch
  delegate :tree, to: :branch
end
```

Then for a single query:

```
Leaf.joins(:branch).group('branches.tree_id').count

And for a query for each tree:

Tree.find_each do |tree|
  Branch.where(tree_id: tree.id).joins(:leaves).count('leaves.id')
end
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Could u eloborate a bit?, where does the threes.id reference too and the branches / leaves? I feel like i'm missing something.

Comment: this can be simplified to `Tree.joins(branches: :leaves).select('count(leaves.id)')`

Comment: @Mischa this is a simple joins with ActiveRecord and then a specific select to count every leaves linked to each Tree.

Comment: Corrected the answer, to make it simpler

Comment: But this goes inside the trees.each do |tree| loop?

Comment: I've tried implementing this but it just keeps giving the same answer, and i need to get the amount of leaves per tree

Comment: it keeps giving {3=>1}, but I need to know the amount of leaves on each tree.

Comment: well, in this case the 3 is an id of your tree, and 1 is the count of leaves

Comment: I get that, but how do I rewrite the code so that it iterates over every tree and tells me the amount of leaves. I'll update my question.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example how you can do it for each tree

Comment: Thanks, don't have time to check this today, i'll look at it tomorow.

Comment: I think this is what I need, but for some reason i get a noMethod error;  undefined method `joins'

Comment: *I have the same association in my models

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Fixed the answer

Comment: Thanks alot, I marked your answer as correct. I found another way of fixing my problem aswell. Do you have any idea on whether one is better/faster then the other? I've updated my question.